# How to find a pin compatible IC?

Tags: integrated-circuit, components

Do we have any website or service where we can mention our IC part number and get alternative pin-compatible part numbers?

Right now what I do it all manually,

1. go to mouser/digikey like portals
2. Filter for IC category(like DC-DC Converter), filter for package(TO-220) and then go through each ones symbol to see what matches from pins' point of view
3. out of what filters out, further check by going inside the datasheet for further technical parameters for a match.

Any idea, how this could be done differently?

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to replace an obsolete part, sometimes the newest version of the data sheet will tell you what the modern replacements from the same manufacturer are, and sometimes they'll tell you if they're pin-compatible.  AD does this for many of their older inamps, for example.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But, this is not enough many a time. Designers need to have alternate parts from different manufacturers to be safe from a supply chain point of view. During COVID when I was working on my customer projects, I had to invest long hours figuring out alternative compatible parts. I have that list compiled (not sharing my blog link else it will be banned) for easy reference. I heard Silcon experts have portal which can find pin compatible part, would nice to know if someone has tah experience? I wish we have search portal kind of facility :)